# Java Import build.gradle file for minecraft mod

Tags: java, gradle

I have been following this tutorial - https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/
- and I am stuck on this section - Launch IDEA and choose to open/import the build.gradle file, using the default gradle wrapper choice. While you wait for this process to finish, you can open the gradle panel, which will get filled with the gradle tasks once importing is completed.

How do I import the build.gradle file? what is the build.gradle file? what does it do? I am new to coding, any help is appreciated. thx

Comment: https://gradle.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Launch IDEA and select "File" → "New" → "Project from Existing Sources"
2. Select `build.gradle` file from the unpacked archive from the site you've provided
   [image]
3. Check wrapper settings on the next screen. Leave the defaults.
   [image]
4. Wait till IDEA builds the projects and makes indexes.
5. Happy hacking!

`build.gradle` is basically a build configuration file. It describes the way a piece of software is made. Like: where is the source code, what are the project's dependencies, where to get and how to link them, how to test and so on.

Speaking about particular `build.gradle` from `forge-mdk`:

---

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url = "https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'
```

This part applies `net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge` plugin that, I guess, is used to build Minecraft mods. As this is a third-party plugin `buildscript` block adds a repository (`https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven`) where it can be downloaded.

---

---

```
version = "1.0"
group = "com.yourname.modid" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "modid"
```

This part describes the result ("artifact") of the projects. It has version `1.0`, name `modid` and will be published (if published) under `com.yourname.modid` group. This is a [Maven related vocabulary](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates). I guess, you'll need to replace this values with your own.

---

---

```
sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = '1.8' // Need this here so eclipse task generates correctly.
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

Here you state that the projects is built with Java 8

---

---

```
minecraft {
    version = "1.12.2-14.23.5.2775"
    runDir = "run"

    mappings = "snapshot_20171003"
}
```

Here you configure `net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge` plugin that you've added previously. Basically, any plugin can expose it's own configuration block and you'll need to read the docs to know what do the values mean.

---

---

```
dependencies {
    …
}
```

The project has no dependencies yet, thus empty `dependencies` block

---

---

```
processResources {
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'

        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }

    // copy everything else except the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Here you configure built-int `processResources` task that… processes resources. As you see, things are self-descriptive in Gradle. Tasks are Java classes that has documentation. For example, [here are the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html) for `ProcessResources`. [One more link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) for DSL reference

---

Hope this answer will get you some info to start with!

Comment: @SamzSakerz why is this offtopic? can you clarify as to why you flagged it?